# zeromq/AMQP plugable?

Tags: message-queue, amqp, zeromq

[1] I was reading through the AMQP standard, and it seems that there is a clear separation between the exchange, queue and binding component. However, looking at the zeromq docs, it doesn't seem as if zeromq allows you to plug in your own exchange/queue/bindings implementation.

[2] Also, is there any AMQP framework available where I don't need to worry about the protocol details and just plug in my implementations for each of these components and expect it to work? (something like fuse for AMQP).

Update: I think zeromq isn't an AMQP compliant messaging system and doesn't have the concept of binding, so I think the 1st question could be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache Qpid http://qpid.apache.org allows you to build your own plugins. The docs for how to build a plugin are sparse at best, but there are plugins in the source kit you can use as examples.

Comment: There is a ZeroMQ bridge for AMQP which does two things. It lets you plug ZeroMQ apps into an AMQP infrastructure, and it allows you to bridge two AMQP MQ brokers to create loosely couple confederations.

Answer (score 4):

RabbitMQ supports plugins too.  Here is an example called Shovel, which is a relay: http://www.lshift.net/blog/2010/02/01/rabbitmq-shovel-message-relocation-equipment

You can also write your own custom exchanges if you are willing to build from source.  Making this properly pluggable is on our roadmap.

I hope this helps!  If you have questions please do not hesitate to email the rabbitmq-discuss list.

Cheers

alexis

Answer (score 1):

[1] Yes, AMQP support was dropped from zeromq.